# Accessing indexes as first columns of matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have data that is output from a computational chemistry program (Gaussian09) which contains sets of Force Constant data.  The data is arranged with indexes as the first 2-4 columns (quadratic, cubic and quartic FC's are calculated).  As an example the cubic FC's look something like this, and MatLab has read them in successfully so I have the correct matrix:

```
cube=[
1  1  1  5  5  5
1  1  2  6  6  6
.
.
4  1  1  8  8  8
4  2  1  9  9  9
4  3  1  7  7  7 ]
```

I need a way to access the last 3 columns when feeding in the indices of the first 3 columns.  Something along the lines of

```
>>index=find([cube(:,1)==4 && cube(:,2)==3 && cube(:,3)==1]);
```

Which would give me the row number of the data that is index [ 4 3 1 ] and allow me to read out the values [7 7 7] which I need within loops to calculate anharmonic frequencies.

Is there a way to do this without a bunch of loops?

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Comment: I figured out a very unflattering way to solve this:

    >>index=find([cube(:,1)==4 & cube(:,2)==3 & cube(:,3)==1]==1)

Which generates a vector from the [cube...] section which contains 0 if no match and 1 if a match, then searches for the 1 in the list.  As the list is non-repeating (only one possible match) there is only one 1 in the list and that index is provided.  Maybe it will help someone else someday so I'm posting what I did.

Answer (score 2):

You have already found one way to solve this, by using `&` in your expression (allowing you to make non-scalar comparisons).

Another way is to use `ismember`:

`index = find(ismember(cube(:,1:3),[4 3 1]));`

Note that in many cases, you may not even need the call to `find`: the binary vector returned by the comparisons or `ismember` can directly be used to index into another array.